# Play framework Retrieve old record of the same object before saving

Tags: java, database, playframework, record, playframework-1.x

**View :**

```
#{form @UserController.editUser()}


<input type="hidden" value=${user?.id} name="user.id">


  #{input key:'user.instructions', label: 'Instructions', value: user?.instructions /}               

//// Assume the value of the instructions is "Old" (currently in the database) and the user changes it in the view to "New" using the input box

***(input is a tag I created.)***



  <div class="form-actions">

          <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="event" value="update">      

                     <i class="icon-save"></i> Save

          </button>

</div>

#{/form}
```

**Controller :**

```
public static void editUser(User user) {

User old = User.findById(user.id);            

 /// Right here I need the old record before i edit it. How do i get the old value? That is, i need record with user.instructions = "Old".   I always get the record where user.instructions = "New" even though it is not saved in the database

user.save();                           

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is happen because, after the form is submitted, Play!Framework JPA object binding make the change to your data on memory (not the data on database, because it have not been persisted).

I have tried this code and it works to me.. :) To overcome this problem, your `editUser` controller action may look like below:

```
public static void editUser(User user) {
   JPA.em().detach(user); // detach framework managed user object
   User old = User.findById(user.id); // get old value from database (get original data)

   // in this scope, "old" variable has same value as in database
   ...

   user = JPA.em().merge(user); // tell framework to manage user object again and reassign variable reference
   user.save(); // persist change to database
}
```

---

> This article can be a good reference:
>
> - [Detaching and Merging JPA Entity](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach)